# audio controls in MVC .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5-audio

When I try to play a network recoding inside a razor page in an MVC .net core 3.1 page, the playback button is gray-out.

I am using Chrome 102.0, and all content is allowed for that page in the site settings.

Since I am debugging in visual studio the certificate is recognized as a secure connection.

Finally, the internal UNC path is valid, and if I place it in the browser address bar, the recording does play as expected.

Here is a sample of what the code looks like inside the razor page:

```
@page
@model TestStreamRecording.Pages.playerModel
@{
}


<audio controls src="\\server.local\shares\folderone\subfolder\vendor\sample.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you are trying to link the browser to physical file, while the browser attempt to access it as web resource.

I can think of 2 options:

1. Use Static files middleware and place the mp3 in the application wwwroot folder
2. Create file stream end point

---

Option 1 is easy, but you have to move the file to wwwroot folder, and it is static solution:

In startup.cs ensure you have

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then simply move the audio file to wwwroot folder and in the view

```
<audio controls>
    <source src='/audio.mp3' type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

audio.mp3 is sample file here

---

Option 2 to stream the file:

First create a stream endpoint in a controller

```
    public IActionResult Stream()
    {
        var path = "Your storage path here. ex :
\\server.local\shares\folderone\subfolder\vendor\sample.mp3");
        var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        return new FileStreamResult(fs, "audio/mp3")
        {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true,
        };
    }
```

Link the audio player to the file

```
<audio controls>
    <source src='/home/stream' type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```